# Jenkins declarative Pipeline: How to define UNSTABLE state

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In Declarative Pipelines it's not possible to use the try{} catch{} method to parse result of a stage.
I need to set the status to UNSTABLE depending on the output of an sh script, any idea of how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post-steps feature in Declarative Pipeline. For example:

```
pipeline {  
    stages {
        stage('some stage') {
            steps {}
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
          // here you can process the output of Shell script and set the build status
        }
        success {
          //Only Success Scenarios
        }
        failure {
         //Only when Failure happens
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above answer only explains how to detect the state of failure or success without using a Scripted Pipeline "try/catch" block. It does not explain how to set the status of the job to UNSTABLE. What should be done to set it UNSTABLE?

Comment: set currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'. More details here https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline